# DocumentDB Stored Procedure return only 100 documents each request?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am used search Query on collection it will get 1000 records but when i return to client side i am getting only 100 records on request.what i have to do, for get all documents which satisfied search query.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Document DB limits the amount of results you can get in one response. It's a form of paging, which prevents you from accidentally retrieving millions of items.

This fact should be clearly visible in the portal:
[image]

You can click "Next page" to get more results, but you can't get all results in one click.

.NET SDK may hide this complexity from you by handling paging internally, so the following code will iterate through the whole result set:

```
foreach (var item in client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection, query))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: i wood like to get more records using .net sdk, tell me how it will be?

Comment: @chenchukrishna Updated the answer

Comment: thankyou @mikhail i will test it. and update this answer status